# Hows the "@" sign used in some formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In excel 2013 - click the Menu to make a new document. In template suggestions select or search and find "warehouse inventory".

Cell J5 has this:

```
=[@QTY]*[@COST]
```

This is a subtitute reference for

```
=G5*I5
```

I'm assuming this has to do with the bunch of named ranges that are defined.

I don't need you to explain it to me step by step. I just don't know what I'm looking at and how to ask google to send me to the appropriate tutorials for it.

I need to know how to be able to make the above mentioned substitute references and how to understand the named range.

```
=InventoryList[[#Headers],[SKU]]
```

Because I apparently understand only basic ones such as

```
=sheet'!$A$5:$A$10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't have just named ranges, but ranges converted to table.

And the search term you need to use when you need more information on them is **structured reference**.

From your question

- `@` means that you're referring to the same row of the table in which role the formula entered.
- `[[#Headers],...]` refers to the header cell of the specified column.

You can find official information [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking at a sheet with a Table. Take a look at [Microsoft's page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) explaining structured references within tables.

---

For the sake of preventing link rot, here are the highlights:

```
╔════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ This item:     ║ Refers to:                                                                   ║
╠════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ #All           ║ The entire table, including column headers, data, and totals (if any).       ║
║ #Data          ║ Just the data rows.                                                          ║
║ #Headers       ║ Just the header row.                                                         ║
║ #Totals        ║ Just the total row. If none exists, then it returns null.                    ║
║                ║                                                                              ║
║ #This Row      ║ Just the cells in the same row as the formula.                               ║
║ or             ║ These specifiers can’t be combined with any other special item specifiers.   ║
║ @              ║ Use them to force implicit intersection behavior for the reference or to     ║
║ or             ║ override implicit intersection behavior and refer to single values from a    ║
║ @[Column Name] ║ column. Excel automatically changes #This Row specifiers to the shorter @    ║
║                ║ specifier in tables that have more than one row of data. But if your table   ║
║                ║ has only one row, Excel doesn’t replace the #This Row specifier, which may   ║
║                ║ cause unexpected calculation results when you add more rows. To avoid        ║
║                ║ calculation problems, make sure you enter multiple rows in your table before ║
║                ║ you enter any structured reference formulas.                                 ║
╚════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: If microsoft's links rot we'll use the search word I asked for. And if the internet rots and we can't find any help on it. Excel will be the least of our worries wont it :)